# EJB3.0/JPA manytomany relationship between entitybeans

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am working with Java EE JSP/EJB3 and I have a problem implementing relations between tables.

As a test example to explain my problem I came up with a Car Model and a Brand relation. In this web application The user creates the brands first. then create the cars because a car cannot exist without one or more brands. a brand can have many cars and a Car can fall under many brands. Furthermore I wish that from Brand I can access the cars like the following brand.cars and from Cars access the brands like car.brands. And all this is driven by Car since it will be created last.

I don't know if the above reasoning is the best way of implementing this. The idea is to be able to access both ways with much less of a problem.

```
public class Brand implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="brand_name")
    private String brand_name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="cars") 
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

The following is the car entity bean:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

   @JoinTable(name = "CarBrand",
       joinColumns =
       @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
       inverseJoinColumns =
       @JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private List<Brand> brands;
}
```

I manage to create a Brand but when I try to create a Car with a particular Brand it gives me the following

```
WARNING: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL121201171525140' defined on 'BRAND'.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO Brand
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Show us the code that throws this exception. It looks like you're persisting a brand that already exists.

Comment: There seem to be several errors in your code. Classes should both be annotated with `@Entity`, `Car.brands` should have some relational annotation, e.g. `@ManyToMany` and I think `Brand.cars` should have a `mappedBy = "brands"` attribute for its `@ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: I had a mistake indeed instead I implemented it with a reference table and worked like a charm. I will give more details on what I did later this week just for others to find a solution if they encounter the same problem. at Arjan Tijms i had the @Entity but I omitted it in the post just for the sake of brevity not even the entity names are the same but for questions a usually go for simple and understandable names :)